# Is the data in a common table expression static?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm wondering if the data in a CTE is static (does it stay the same when changes are made to the original tables it was created from) - I think the answer is yes, but I want to make sure.  Example:

```
DECLARE @TSCourseID as INT = 123456789;

WITH CTE as
(
SELECT
    TSRegistrants.TSRegistrantID
    ,TSRegistrants.Name
    ,TSRegistrants.Email
    ,TSRegistrants.PhoneNumber
FROM TSRegCourseDetail
    JOIN TSRegistrants
        ON TSRegCourseDetail.TSRegistrantID = TSRegistrants.TSRegistrantID
WHERE TSRegCourseDetail.TSCourseID = @TSCourseID
    AND TSRegistrants.Name in ('User List')
)

UPDATE TSRegCourseDetail
SET TSCourseID = 987654321
WHERE TSRegistrantID in (select TSRegistrantID from CTE)
```

1) Would this change the data in the CTE? This query would empty it if so; I'm hoping it doesn't

2) Also, would update/set from select TSRegistrantID from CTE work/be any better?

I am not a programmer, just got stuck with the hat for the time being >.<

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CTE is evaluated before the UPDATE takes place, so in the way that you mean, no the data doesn't change.

Also, a CTE can only be used with one select statement (or update or insert). If you want it to be available for multiple statements you need either a temp table or table variable instead.

Comment: Thanks Tab.  I tried using the CTE with multiple select statements, and it looks like after the first one, the CTE was removed as an object; is this what you had in mind with "in the way that you mean"?  Should I be selecting into a #TEMPTABLE instead?

Comment: Yes, a CTE can only be used with one select statement (or update or insert).   If you want it to be available for multiple statements you need either a temp table or table variable instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you post that as an answer?  When you do, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a CTE for this at all:

```
DECLARE @TSCourseID AS INT = 123456789

UPDATE  cd
SET     cd.TSCourseID = 987654321
FROM    TSCourseDetail cd
        INNER JOIN TSRegistrants r ON cd.TSRegistrantID = r.TSRegistrantID
WHERE   cd.TSRegistrantID = @TSCourseID
        AND TSRegistrants.Name IN ( 'User List' )
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, however there are multiple queries that I wanted to run based off of the data returned in the CTE, and I was unaware that it only persisted for one statement.  I think that using a #TEMPTABLE would be a better option.